# Non static azure function crashes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I ran into a problem with azure functions which has ServiceBus as a trigger. The problem is that I want to inject some variables into the class that handles the functions. The function below:

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusListener")]
public async void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("event", "subscription",
   Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
   string sbEvent, IDictionary<string, object> userProperties)
{
    var a = sbEvent
}
```

Crashes with the errors

```
[2021-03-10T16:36:06.965Z] System.Private.Uri: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString').
[2021-03-10T16:36:07.018Z] Message processing error (Action=UserCallback, ClientId=MessageReceiver1[REDACTED]/Subscriptions/[REDACTED], EntityPath=[REDACTED]/Subscriptions/[REDACTED], Endpoint=[REDACTED].servicebus.windows.net)
```

While the code below parses the requests as expected

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusListener")]
public static async void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("event", "subscription",
   Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
   string sbEvent, IDictionary<string, object> userProperties)
{
    var a = sbEvent
}
```

The problem is that I'm 100% that this code worked before and it started misbehaving recently.

Answer (score 0):

Ehh, the problem was that the constructor was throwing an exception but it wasn't reported anywhere.